# GLTF export settings: how to remember export path?

Tags: gltf, settings

In the gltf export menu, there is a checkbox to remember export settings. However, there seems to be no way to remember the export path. Whenever I open this file and export it to gltf, I must set the file path. It is not remembered across sessions.

Is there something I'm missing? Surely I am not the only one annoyed by this?

Thanks a bunch!

Using Blender 3.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same question yesterday.

The only info I could find in Github is about saved settings, but the filepath, while moved across classes and functions seems to be never be saved.

The fact that the extension modal loading redirect you in the last know path seems to be a BlenderExporter extension specific feature not available through the python API.

Upon Further inspection and tests

Here is a work around but you will have to alter the GLTF2 addon:

In the main `__init__.py` file
at line `678` add `'filepath'` in order to enable the saving of the filepath

Reload the addon (deactivate / reactivate in the preferences)

In another script you can then access this data

```py
known_path = context.scene['glTF2ExportSettings']['filepath']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: The direct answer to be understood is that it seems that there is no exposition through the python API to Export Operator's saved filepath yet.